# How to instantiate initFlowbite() globally instead of per page/component in NuxtJS?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, flowbite

I have a fairly new Nuxt3 application that I am attempting to switch over to [Flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/nuxt-js/). One thing I ran in to was getting javascript-dependent components working properly, and since discovered that it was because I needed to import and instantiate initFlowbite(). This appears to only work on the direct page or component that contains those elements though.

For example, I have a Vue page with several tooltips. If I add the following code, it works.

```js
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

onMounted(() => {
  initFlowbite();
});
```

If I add that same code to App.vue, it no longer works.

Is there a way to globally instantiate this, as opposed to importing and instantiating inside of an onMounted() function possibly hundreds of times as the size of this application grows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a global mixin via a client plugin

`plugins/flowbite.client.ts`

`.server` or `.client` suffix in the file name will load a plugin only on the server or client side.

```js
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.mixin({
        mounted () {
            initFlowbite();
        }
    });
});
```